# Convert Mat image to Image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, mat

I am breaking my head over this:
How do I convert a `cv::Mat` image to a `System::Drawing::Image`

I know every image consists of bytes so you should probably use a byte array but right after that I'm lost. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: You need to [marshal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx) the data from native to managed side.

Comment: Maybe this link may help you: http://frasergreenroyd.com/how-to-convert-opencv-cvmat-to-system-bitmap-to-system-imagesource/.